# How to open a new view on click of Table View Cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, view, tableview

I am developing an iOS app which has a TableView, and I want to do sth that when a cell of the TableView is tapped, a new view opens (and then it can get back to the Table View.) I tried some things like working with segues and new view controllers, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show your progress in code to guide better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, and implement the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Inside that method you can create your new view.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the UITableViewDelegate Protocol :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

For this Protocol the delegate method is below:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

//Create Object for next view controller 

    NextViewController *vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:"NextViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }

}
```